# PHP like static methods in python

Tags: python

I am very new in python. I am writing a daemon in python and in my daemon I have a logger class. Logger class is something I need to use all over my daemon. Now rather that making new instance of the class inside each of my classes or passing an object of the logger class, I want to implement a PHP like static class so that it will cache the database connection inside and I can call it from anywhere without instantiating, Like,

```
Logger::log('This is cool');
```

How can I do it in python?

Comment: checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python

Comment: Have you looked into existing Python loggers (e.g. the `logging` module) and/or their implementation? That's probably a better approach for this particular problem to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module. [logging.getLogger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) ensures

> All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger instance. This means that logger instances never need to be passed between different parts of an application.

For example, at anywhere, when you call `logging.getLogger('the-logger-name')` you always get the same object.

As you want to write your logs to a database, you need to implement your own [handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#handler-objects), which connects to the database, and is hooked with the logger through [logger.addHanlder](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addHandler).

When you implement the handler by deriving from `logging.Handler`, you don't have to override every method - checkout how [BufferingHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BufferingHandler) does in Python's [handlers implementation](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/logging/handlers.py).